# EF7 setting child object to null issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I`am using EF7 rc2 in my project.
There is two related classes

```
public sealed class Member
{   
    ......   
    public MemberState State { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MemberState
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Org Org { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And EF configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MemberState>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("State");
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);    
    entity.Property<Guid>("Idf_Org");
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Org).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Idf_Org");    
    .....    
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Member>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    entity.Property<Guid>("Idf_State");
    entity.HasOne(member => member.State).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Idf_State");
});
```

So, in some time i whant to set null to Org field in MembersState.

```
mwmbwe.State = new MemberState()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ....
    Org = null
 };          
 _provider.SaveChanges();
```

An exception occurs when saving changes into database. EF trying to insert related Org item with null PK. **Is any way to awoid this ?**

Also tryed to solve this issue by direct ExecuteSqlCommand, and than fetching new MemberState from EF provider, but it raises exception too: 
*"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

In database field, containing Idf_Org marked as 'Allow null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devil is in details )

Mortezas answer was very helpful, but after applying it i have had this exeption:
*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The foreign key {'Idf_Org'} on entity type 'MemberState' cannot be marked as optional because it does not contain any property of a nullable type. Any foreign key can be marked as required, but only foreign keys with at least one property of a nullable type and which is not part of primary key can be marked as optional.*

so, true decision was

```
entity.Property<Guid?>("Idf_Org");
entity.HasOne(e => e.Org).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Idf_Org").IsRequired(false);
```

It works only wen shadow property is marked nullable too

Comment: That is correct, the other (better) way is to have a nullable FK property on your *MemberState* object that is mapped to *Idf_Org* instead of shadowing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the association between *MemberState* and *Org* is optional then you need to specify this in your fluent API:

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.Org)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey("Idf_Org")
      .IsRequired(false);
```

As a result EF Core will let you save a MemberState without an Org at runtime.

Comment: Actually, i have tried this, and it is seems as true decision, But after reconfiguration my ASP.NET core 1.0 application cannot start. And it is quite strange - no exceptions, or output warnings are fired

Comment: UPD
output contains this:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll